# Rule Based Alert System - Data Alerts

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssas, alert

I need to set a Rule-based Alert system based on SQL Data warehouse Values. I am using SSIS for ETL, SSAS For Cubes and SSRS for Reports. As far as I have managed to find out SSRS has this functionality, but I didn't manage to set alerts via SSRS. It needs SharePoint but I don't have Share point Server. can you help where I can set it.?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want an alerting mechanism similar to the one found in [SharePoint alerts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-view-or-delete-sharepoint-alerts-99dfb19c-9a90-4a8c-aba1-aa8c8afb0de2), BUT using SSRS.

> Alerts are notifications of changes to content on a site that you receive as e-mail messages or text messages to your mobile phone

SSRS has a notification mechanism called [subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/subscriptions-and-delivery-reporting-services).

> E-mail reports to individual users and groups. Create a subscription and specify a group alias or e-mail alias to receive a report that you want to distribute

[image]
Essentially, you or the user can create a subscription to have the Report delivered to them.

You create the subscription for a report

[image]